# New laptop for gaming/work, around 1000 €

Tags: laptop, gaming

I'm going to buy a laptop for both gaming and coding (I already have a bigger, powerful PC for most of the games though, but I also want to play on the laptop).

I want something :

- nice-looking
- quick to boot (A SSD for the OS seems mandatory, or a hybrid drive)
- A good battery life (3+ hours)
- With an OS (W10)
- Comfortable for long sessions of coding
- Reliable in the long term

I don't mind about not having an optical drive.

Are there brands I should avoid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally bought an [Asus ROG G551JW-DM379T](http://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B0166VYZI4?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00) following the advices of my SysAdmin (Quoting : "Asus is GOOD").

- It is not too flashy
- Features an hybrid HDD (1Tb + 24Gb)
- Windows 10
- Good processor (Core i7) and graphics card (GeForce GTX960M)
- Was quite "cheap" (980€, which allowed me to take some accessories with it)